# Combine .htaccess files to a single working one

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess files on every subfolder in **demo.mydomain.net** to redirect to **mydomain.net** without redirecting image/js files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/load
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.net" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/load/images
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.net" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/load/scripts
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.net" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/load/styles
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.net" [R=301,L]
```

Is there any way I can combine these to a single working file and save it to where my index file is?

Comment: You need a pattern match rather than a direct match. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146200/regex-to-match-a-url-pattern-for-a-htaccess-file

Answer (score 2):

You would need the following combined rule within the `.htaccess` in your directory mapped to `demo.mydomain.net`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/load(/(images|scripts|styles))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.net [R=301,L]
```

The above `%{REQUEST_URI}` regex intercepts all four URL paths.

Comment: why not: `RewriteRule ^load(/(images|scripts|styles))?/?$ http://mydomain.net [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: That would only match directories. I may be wrong but I think OP wants to intercepts image/js/css requests. If you meant that regex could have been on the single line then man, there's this one guy and I hope he doesn't see your comment, 'coz I might get down voted again for one extra line! :D

Comment: lol :) I know who you are talking about. I have also handled that "one guy" many times. But yes I meant to avoid `RewriteCond` altogether and no it won't just match directories since `/?$` means trailing slash is  optional. You can probably use: `RewriteRule ^load(/(images|scripts|styles))? http://mydomain.net [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: Yes, but you had a `$` there :) The one you have now is okay though. But, you know what? I like the single-line `RewriteRule` when doing a negative lookahead `^(?!nothis1)...` Way cooler and people go like WTF! :)

Comment: Yup that's right +1 for a good answer. Wonder why OP hasn't accepted it yet.